# moveToThread for a member function

Tags: c++, qt5, qthread

Is it possible to move a member function to a new Thread instead of the whole class?

To put this into context:

```
    class FooBar : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    // some other function that deals with the UI changes    
    private:
        get foo();
    };
```

Is it possible to only move `foo()` to a new thread? The entire class has a lot of UI calls and other components which may not be thread-safe. I will really appreciate any help or else I will have to reorganize the class and move `foo()` to a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move a function to a thread like this. `moveToThread` changes the [affinity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) of that object to that thread. This means more or less that the signals of that object will be sent to the event loop of the new thread.

I think that you are looking for `QtConcurrent` for this type of task:

> The QtConcurrent::run() function runs a function in a separate thread.
>   The return value of the function is made available through the QFuture
>   API.

```
 extern void aFunctionWithArguments(int arg1, double arg2, const QString &string);

 int integer = ...;
 double floatingPoint = ...;
 QString string = ...;

 QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(aFunctionWithArguments, integer, floatingPoint, string);
```

See the [Qt Concurrent Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qtconcurrent.html) and [QFuture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuture.html) for more details.